# How can i move the QWidget in QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I want to move the QPushButton or kind of QWidget in QGraphicsView for example QListWidet, QTableWidget etc.

So, I used  QGraphicsProxyWidget.

Then I clicked the widget and drag. But It is not moving.

How can i move QWidget?

This is my code.

```
ui->graphicsView->setGeometry(0,0,geometry().width(),geometry().height());
scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, geometry().width(), geometry().height(), this);

ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

btn =new QPushButton(NULL);
QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = scene->addWidget(btn);
proxy->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable|QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
scene->addItem(proxy);
```

Can you tell me What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: A common approach would be to handle mouse down, mouse release and mouse move events of the main frame (where the button is) and then redraw the button again and refresh the main frame.

Comment: Umm.. I didnt understand your comment. So, Could you show me the small example? Thanks macroland @macroland

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Cause

In your case you cannot move the button, because although you have made the proxy movable, the button handles the mouse input differently in order to implement its *clicked* functionality. In other words, on a mouse press, how could a move action be differentiated from a click action?

## Solution

My solution would be to make the button part of a somewhat bigger *QGraphicsRectItem*. The latter will serve as a draggable handle, i.e. if the user interacts with the button - it clicks, but if the other portion of the *QGraphicsRectItem* (not covered by the button) is interacted with, the button could be moved around.

## Example

Here is an example showing exactly how to do that:

```
auto *item = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 75, 40);
auto *proxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(item);
auto *btn = new QPushButton(tr("Click me"));

btn->setGeometry(0, 0, 77, 26);

item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
item->setBrush(Qt::darkYellow);

proxy->setWidget(btn);
proxy->setPos(0, 15);
proxy->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable|QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);

scene->addItem(item);
```

**Note:** To make this work it is important to set the parent of `proxy` to `item`.

Comment: Thanks for your ansewr! Have a nice day.

Comment: @yoon, Was that helpful to you?

Comment: @yoon You could mark as correct if the answer did work.

Comment: @scopchanov, Sure, It is very helpful information. Actually, I want to move widget without QGraphicsRectItem. But in my researching result, Maybe It is impossible. If you know how to move widget without QGraphicsRectitem or any container. Could you give some information? –

Comment: @yoon, if you know how to differentiate between moving the widget and interacting with it, it is possible to achieve this without a container.

Comment: @scopchanov, How can i interact it?

Comment: @yoon, if the widget is a button, clicking it is an interaction.

Comment: @scopchanov, Is your saying that I move the position to the inner code when I press the button?

Comment: @yoon, you want to move a widget, let’s say a QPushButton, without having a QGraphicsItem, right? And I say it is possible, but only if you find a way to differentiate between two events: 1. the user pressed the mouse on the button with the intent of clicking it and 2. The user pressed the mouse on the button with the intent of moving it. An example of such differentiation could be _press_ vs. _press and hold_. In this case you don’t need QGraphicsRectItem, but you have to subclass QPushButton and reimplement the mouse events.